# Dependent probabilities find out the different combinations of rolls that add up to a certain number when rolling two dice

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

I am trying to create an algorithm to calculate the dependent probabilities for rolling two dice adding up to a certain number. The dependent probabilities part is fine but I am trying to find all the possible number combinations. Rolling two dice at once means that your range of numbers will be from 2 - 12. I would like to find all the different combinations of a two sided dice that will add up to a target number.

For example if the target number is 8:
The amount of different combinations are the following:
(2,6)(6,2)(5,3)(3,5)(4,4)(2,2,2,2)(3,3,2)(2,3,3)(3,2,3)

The only code I could create to find number combinations is the following code below:

```
source = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
targets = [25]

p = [[a for n in range(2, 13) for a in it.combinations(source, n) if sum(a) == t] for t in targets]
[dict(zip(targets, a)) for a in it.product(*p) if len(sum(a, tuple())) == len(set(sum(a, tuple())))]


print(p)
```

The problem with the above code is that it doesn't show all the different combinations in different orders and also repeated number combinations.

For example with target number 8:
(2,6) adds up to eight
however the code above does not include the other combination (6,2)

Another example with target number 8:
(4,4) adds up to eight however, is in not included in the output in the above code.

My end goal for is that the algorithm is able to find all the possible combinations for larger numbers e.g. 25. I would like to know if there is a solution based on the existing code or new code that solves the problems above. Preferably the solution being in python however, I am open to other languages.

Comment: If you take combinations without replacement of a single monotonically increasing sequence there's no way to get things like (x,x), and order doesn't matter in combinations so you won't get both (x,y) and (y,x). It sounds like you want permutations with replacement instead of combinations. That or sampling from n copies of the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you do with these partitions afterward, there might be a better algorithm, but I think this is what you're asking for.

```
def all_rolls_with_sum(target):
    if target == 0:
        yield []
        return
    for roll in range(2, min(target, 12) + 1):
        for rolls in all_rolls_with_sum(target - roll):
            rolls.append(roll)
            yield rolls


import pprint

pprint.pprint(list(all_rolls_with_sum(8)))
```

Output:

```
[[2, 2, 2, 2],
 [4, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 2],
 [2, 4, 2],
 [6, 2],
 [3, 2, 3],
 [2, 3, 3],
 [5, 3],
 [2, 2, 4],
 [4, 4],
 [3, 5],
 [2, 6],
 [8]]
```